# Https FBML Height Issue ,

Tags: performance, facebook, height

When ever i move to HTTPS VERSION OF my app then Height of the app is not auto resized ,
Can you provide us asny solution to handle this problem.

We have Optimize to oAUTH 2.0

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you are not loading the facebook javascript library through HTTPS so the browser is blocking insecure content.

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use: FB.Canvas.setSize
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setSize/

Example:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
<script>
  (function(d, s, id) {  
  var js,fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];   if (d.getElementById(id))
  {return;}   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";  
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script','facebook-jssdk'));

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'YOURAPPID', status: true, cookie: true,
             xfbml: true, oauth: true});

    setTimeout(function() { FB.Canvas.setSize(); }, 500);  
    // optionally, you can safely start up auto resize
    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
  };
</script>
```

Greetings,
Fredyy

Comment: How to Use How can i place that in Code , can you give one example